# automatically highlights words in the textpane

Tags: java, user-interface, textarea, jtextarea

I have this code from java2s.com and I just modified it. I don't know if I need to use the runnable or the documentlistener so that the application will automatically highlight the word that was defined in the code. I don't have much knowledge about the two, I tried the runnable but I encountered errors. Can someone help me? Here's the code.

```
public class Sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
  String word = "";

Highlighter highlighter = new UnderlineHighlighter(null);

textPane.setHighlighter(highlighter);
textPane.setText("This is a test");

final WordSearcher searcher = new WordSearcher(textPane);
final UnderlineHighlighter uhp = new UnderlineHighlighter(Color.red);
  String w = "i";
  int offset = searcher.search(w);
  if (offset == -1) {
    return;
  }
  try {
    textPane.scrollRectToVisible(textPane.modelToView(offset));
  } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
  }

textPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  @Override
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
    searcher.search(word);
  }

  @Override
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
    searcher.search(word);
  }

  @Override
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
  }
});
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//f.add(panel, "South");
f.add(new JScrollPane(textPane), "Center");
f.setSize(400, 400);
f.setVisible(true);
}
public static String word;

public static Highlighter highlighter = new UnderlineHighlighter(null);
}

class WordSearcher {
public WordSearcher(JTextComponent comp) {
this.comp = comp;
this.painter = new UnderlineHighlighter.UnderlineHighlightPainter(
    Color.red);
}
public int search(String word) {
   int firstOffset = -1;
   Highlighter highlighter = comp.getHighlighter();


Highlighter.Highlight[] highlights = highlighter.getHighlights();
for (int i = 0; i < highlights.length; i++) {
  Highlighter.Highlight h = highlights[i];
  if (h.getPainter() instanceof 
UnderlineHighlighter.UnderlineHighlightPainter) {
    highlighter.removeHighlight(h);
  }
}

if (word == null || word.equals("")) {
  return -1;
}


String content = null;
try {
  Document d = comp.getDocument();
  content = d.getText(0, d.getLength()).toLowerCase();
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
  // Cannot happen
  return -1;
}

word = word.toLowerCase();
int lastIndex = 0;
int wordSize = word.length();

while ((lastIndex = content.indexOf(word, lastIndex)) != -1) {
  int endIndex = lastIndex + wordSize;
  try {
    highlighter.addHighlight(lastIndex, endIndex, painter);
  } catch (BadLocationException e) {
    // Nothing to do
  }
  if (firstOffset == -1) {
    firstOffset = lastIndex;
  }
  lastIndex = endIndex;
}

return firstOffset;
}

protected JTextComponent comp;

protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;

}

class UnderlineHighlighter extends DefaultHighlighter {
public UnderlineHighlighter(Color c) {
painter = (c == null ? sharedPainter : new UnderlineHighlightPainter(c));
}


public Object addHighlight(int p0, int p1) throws BadLocationException {
return addHighlight(p0, p1, painter);
}

public void setDrawsLayeredHighlights(boolean newValue) {
// Illegal if false - we only support layered highlights
if (newValue == false) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "UnderlineHighlighter only draws layered highlights");
}
super.setDrawsLayeredHighlights(true);
}

public static class UnderlineHighlightPainter extends
  LayeredHighlighter.LayerPainter {
public UnderlineHighlightPainter(Color c) {
  color = c;
}

public void paint(Graphics g, int offs0, int offs1, Shape bounds,
    JTextComponent c) {
  // Do nothing: this method will never be called
}

public Shape paintLayer(Graphics g, int offs0, int offs1, Shape bounds,
    JTextComponent c, View view) {
  g.setColor(color == null ? c.getSelectionColor() : color);

  Rectangle alloc = null;
  if (offs0 == view.getStartOffset() && offs1 == view.getEndOffset()) {
    if (bounds instanceof Rectangle) {
      alloc = (Rectangle) bounds;
    } else {
      alloc = bounds.getBounds();
    }
  } else {
    try {
      Shape shape = view.modelToView(offs0,
          Position.Bias.Forward, offs1,
          Position.Bias.Backward, bounds);
      alloc = (shape instanceof Rectangle) ? (Rectangle) shape
          : shape.getBounds();
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(c.getFont());
  int baseline = alloc.y + alloc.height - fm.getDescent() + 1;
  g.drawLine(alloc.x, baseline, alloc.x + alloc.width, baseline);
  g.drawLine(alloc.x, baseline + 1, alloc.x + alloc.width,
      baseline + 1);

  return alloc;
}

protected Color color; // The color for the underline
}


protected static final Highlighter.HighlightPainter sharedPainter = new 
UnderlineHighlightPainter(
  null);

protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You needed help to resolve your errors?

Comment: Please include your stacktrace in your question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code has some import errors? It runs fine with Java 1.8. In this situation it is Ok to use DocumentListener. Made some modifications in main class for finding text "test":

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        String word = "test";

        Highlighter highlighter = new UnderlineHighlighter(null);

        textPane.setHighlighter(highlighter);
        textPane.setText("This is a test");

        final WordSearcher searcher = new WordSearcher(textPane);
        final UnderlineHighlighter uhp = new UnderlineHighlighter(Color.red);
        String w = "i";
        int offset = searcher.search(w);
        if (offset == -1) {
                return;
        }
        try {
                textPane.scrollRectToVisible(textPane.modelToView(offset));
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        }

        textPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                        searcher.search(word);
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                        searcher.search(word);
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                }
        });
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(textPane), "Center");
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
        searcher.search(word);
    }

    public static String word;

    public static Highlighter highlighter = new UnderlineHighlighter(null); 
}
}
```